# How to quickly match if a point is between 2 points, for large lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a dictionary with information about single positions: `position_info`, and info about features `feature_info`. I have to find in which features (can be multiple) the positions are located, so that I can annotate the positions. What I use now is:

```
feature_info = [[1, 10, 'a'],[15, 30, 'b'],[40, 60, 'c'],[55, 71, 'd'],[73, 84, 'e']]
position_info = {5:'some info', 16:'some other info', 75:'last info'}
for pos in position_info.keys():
    for info in feature_info:
        if info[0] <= pos < info[1]:
            print(pos, position_info[pos], info[2])
```

The problem is that `feature_info` contains 800k+ features, and `position_info` 150k positions, and this is quite slow. I can optimize it myself a little bit, but probably there are already methods that do it better than I can, but I have not found them.

### EDIT

So for example this is one way I can think of to speed it up:

```
for info in feature_info:
    for pos in position_info.keys():
        if info[0] <= pos < info[1]:
            print(pos, position_info[pos], info[2])
        if pos > info[1]:
            break
```

if I order the positions I can break when the position is larger than an end position of a feature (if I make sure those are ordered too). However, there must be a better way to do this.

How can I implement this in the fastest way?

### Comparison of the 3 answers

```
import timeit

setup = """
from bisect import bisect
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

position_info = {}

random_number = random.sample(range(9000), 8000)
random_feature_start = random.sample(range(90000), 5000)
random_feature_length = np.random.choice(1000, 5000, replace=True)

for i in random_number:
    position_info[i] = 'test'
feature_info = []
for index, i in enumerate(random_feature_start):
    feature_info.append([i, i+random_feature_length[index],'test'])

"""

p1 = """
sections = sorted(r for a, b, c in feature_info for r in (a,b))
for pos in position_info:
    feature_info[int(bisect(sections, pos) / 2)]
"""

p2 = """
# feature info to dataframe
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(feature_info)

# rename feature df columns
feature_df.rename(index=str, columns={0: "start", 1: "end",2:'name'}, inplace=True)

# positions to dataframe
position_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(position_info, orient='index')
position_df['key'] = position_df.index

# merge dataframes
feature_df['merge'] = 1
position_df['merge'] = 1
merge_df = feature_df.merge(position_df, on='merge')
merge_df.drop(['merge'], inplace=True, axis=1)

# filter where key between start and end
merge_df = merge_df.loc[(merge_df.key > merge_df.start) & (merge_df.key < merge_df.end)] 
"""

p3 = """
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(feature_info)
position_df = pd.DataFrame(position_info, index=[0])
hits = position_df.apply(lambda col: (feature_df [0] <= col.name) & (col.name < feature_df [1])).values.nonzero()
for f, p in zip(*hits):
    position_info[position_df.columns[p]]
    feature_info[f]
"""

print('bisect:',timeit.timeit(p1, setup=setup, number = 3))
print('panda method 1:',timeit.timeit(p2, setup=setup, number = 3))
print('panda method 2:',timeit.timeit(p3, setup=setup, number = 3))
```

bisect: 0.08317881799985116
panda method 1: 29.6151025639997
panda method 2: 16.90901438500032

However, the bisect method only works if there are no overlapping features, e.g.

```
feature_info = [[1, 10, 'a'],[15, 30, 'b'],[40, 60, 'c'],[55, 71, 'd'],[2, 8, 'a_new']]
```

does not work, which does work with the pandas solution.

Comment: Just to be sure, the code works as intended, just needs to be optimized?

Comment: Yes the output is correct, but because it has to loop through all the features for every position it is slow when those both get big. @SunnyPatel I added code of one optimization I can think of that also works (the one I had previously did not)

Comment: Can't you use a binary search to find a feature position that fits? Other positions will be next to it (assuming all is sorted)

Comment: About `feature_info`, are all the ranges in index 0 and 1 non-overlapping and discrete? I was going to give you a solution using binary search.

Comment: No, features can be overlapping, they are all discrete.

Comment: I'm curious to see a time comparison among these answers with massive data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is probably to use a fast library: [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas vectorizes your operations to make them speedy.

```
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(feature_info)
position_df = pd.DataFrame(position_info, index=[0])
hits = position_df.apply(lambda col: (feature_df[0] <= col.name) & (col.name < feature_df[1])).values.nonzero()
for feature, position in zip(*hits):
    print(position_info[position_df.columns[p]], "between", feature_info[f])
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) library and function is amazing for things like this.

We basically create a sorted list of ranges that a feature will fall under. Let me know if you need additional logic for checking if a position doesn't fall within a feature range.

Since `feature_info[n][0:1]` is a range of 2 values, we need to divide the bisect result (which is an index position) by 2.

```
from bisect import bisect

feature_info = [[1, 10, 'a'],[15, 30, 'b'],[40, 60, 'c'],[55, 71, 'd'],[73, 84, 'e']]
position_info = {5:'some info', 16:'some other info', 75:'last info'}
sections = sorted(r for a, b, c in feature_info for r in (a,b))

for pos in position_info:
  print(pos, feature_info[bisect(sections, pos) / 2])
```

This will print the following (you should be able to get all the info you need from this, but I wanted to show the basic result):

```
(16, [15, 30, 'b'])
(75, [73, 84, 'e'])
(5, [1, 10, 'a'])
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that bisect is blazing fast for large data sets because it does operate using binary search.

Answer (score 1):

Is a textual description OK?

Preprocessing:

- sort the positions
- convert list of features into a list of "boundaries" (as in, start indices and end indices for each feature) - these will be triples of (`index`, `start/end`, `feature`). Sort this list by index.

Algorithm (two nested for loops):

- start with empty set of 'current features'
- for each feature boundary:

  - for each position from the range of: from the next position after last-visited position, until the position of current boundary's position:

    - output that this position belongs to each of current features
  - if the current boundary is a start, add it to the current features
  - if the current boundary is an end, remove it from the current features

Note that:

- the outer for loop will execute exactly once for each boundary,
- the inner for loop will execute (in total) exactly once for each position.

This will be fast because you don't need to look at any position or any feature twice in both loops. It will actually approach O(N+M) complexity if the positions don't overlap often (so that the current_features set remains small).

I assumed that there are no duplicate positions; handling these would add a little more complexity but the general approach would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Also using pandas. First converts them to dataframes, then merges, then filters where position info key is between feature info columns.

```
import pandas as pd

feature_info = [[1, 10, 'a'],[15, 30, 'b'],[40, 60, 'c'],[55, 71, 'd'],[73, 84, 'e']]
position_info = {5:'some info', 16:'some other info', 75:'last info'}

# feature info to dataframe
feature_df = pd.DataFrame(feature_info)

# rename feature df columns
feature_df.rename(index=str, columns={0: "start", 1: "end",2:'name'}, inplace=True)

# positions to dataframe
position_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(position_info, orient='index')
position_df['key'] = position_df.index

# merge dataframes
feature_df['merge'] = 1
position_df['merge'] = 1
merge_df = feature_df.merge(position_df, on='merge')
merge_df.drop(['merge'], inplace=True, axis=1)

# filter where key between start and end
merge_df = merge_df.loc[(merge_df.key > merge_df.start) & (merge_df.key < merge_df.end)]
```